# Return error response if a body params is not mentionned in the validator

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using the Laravel [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) to test my incoming request. So to be sure that the request contains an `username` and an `email`, I write something like that:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username'  => 'required',
    'email'     => 'required|email'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json('error', 400);
};
```

But if in my request I have an additionnal params like `name`, the validator will not consider it as an error and will not fail.

Have you an idea how I can make my validator more strict so that the request body match exactly?

Comment: Im not sure i understand the logic of needing to check for request input values that you do not intend to use?  The next question is why is those param's being passed in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it's not a validation fail in the Validator. But you could check if there are extra (unexpected) fields and send a JSON response based on that if you wanted.

Something like this maybe?

```
$validationRules = [
    'username'  => 'required',
    'email'     => 'required|email'
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationRules);

// Check if there are extra (unexpected) fields and fail in that case
$extraFields = $request->except(array_keys($validationRules));
if (count($extraFields) > 0) {
    return response()->json('error because there are extra fields', 400);
}

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json('error', 400);
}

return response()->json('ok', 200);
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Works fine. I didn't know the `except()` function but seems to be a good use here. Little bit sad that it don't exist a `match()` function for the validator

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules can be attached only to properties, so I don't think Laravel's Validator is able to do that. But you still can explicitly forbid certain fields by providing a custom [closure rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-closures) to them, like this:

```php
$denied = function($attr, $value, $fail) {
    $fail("{$attr} is denied.");
};

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username'  => 'required',
    'email'     => 'required|email',
    'name'      => $denied,
    'password'  => $denied
]);
```

Otherwise you need to implement custom validation logic, probably utilizing the rule array from your validator as a white list.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I don't know what extra properties will I can get. So it's not really dynamic and don't really answer my question

Comment: Then Wesley's approach is the way.